# Border styling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried different methods to apply this CSS to the border

```
style="border:thin; border-color: #006633; border-radius: 5px;
```

but it doesn't work. How to style the border with the above CSS?

**HTML**

```
<div style= "left: 400px; position: absolute; top: 50px;" >
    <div style="float: left;>
        <ul class="home">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <ul id="about">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a id="hidden1" href="#">Our Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <ul id="contact">
            <li><a href="#" >Contact Us</li>
            <li><a id="hidden2" href="#">Contact Form</a></li>
            <li><a id="hidden3" href="#">Contact Numbers</a></li>
            <li><a id="hidden4" href="#">Social</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//dropdown menu
$(function() {
    $("ul#about").hover(function() {
        $("#hidden1").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("ul#contact").hover(function() {
        $("#hidden2,#hidden3,#hidden4").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

Comment: you have missing quotes in line 2

Comment: Yes you are totally right! Thank you:)

Comment: I added to the title and question that you are trying to style the border. Please make sure they are as right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrapped the entire code in position absolute.
You need to provide the `width` for the float to work.

Border has 3 components:
 - style -> solid/dashed/double/dotted ...
 - width -> width of the border
 - color -> color

All three are necessary for the border to work.

Comment: but this code: "style="border:thin; border-color: #006633; border-radius: 5px;"

Comment: add border-style:solid

Comment: To which tag? The mother div, the child divs , to each "li"s or anchor tags?

Comment: aaaa now I got it ! Thanks ! let me try it one more time

Comment: to whichever div u want the border. add all three components; style="border: solid thin #006633; border-radius: 5px;

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but it looks like the missing quotes Rhea mentioned are hiding in front of the "style" in your first example.

Comment: ya, actually I got the missing code when I was pasting the code in here, but it didn't work even when it had. I mean the float left part work but the code below:

Comment: "style="border:thin; border-color: #006633; border-radius: 5px;"

Comment: I tried adding it to the parent div, child div, the ul, the li, or even the anchor tag. neither works